# Trouble with return redirect() in flask python

Tags: python, flask

I think the solution should be:

return redirect(url_for(main))

as my terminal tells me I am moving to '/' like I should be, but it doesn't work. I can get

```
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Apr/2018 23:01:36] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

It just doesn't actually take me there.

There has to be a really dumb simple error here. All I want to do is, upon storing the new username and password into the database, return to the home screen, which is listed at '/'. I basically have this exact process in another page, so I don't really see the problem. This is just a crude sign up page to satisfy the requirement for a project, it's more symbolic than anything.

I can also confirm the entry does make it to the database and "here" gets printed.

I feel like

```
return redirect('/')
```

is a valid line.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/flask/flask_redirect_and_errors.htm

```
@app.route('/signUp',methods=['POST','GET'])
def signUp():

    conn = mysql.connect()
    cur = conn.cursor()

    try:
        _name = request.form['inputName']
        _email = request.form['inputEmail']
        _password = request.form['inputPassword']

        if _name and _email and _password:

            cur.callproc('sp_createUser',(_name,_email,_password,))
            print ("Registered")
            data = cur.fetchall()

            conn.commit()
            json.dumps({'message':'User created successfully !'})
            print('here')
            return redirect('/')#not redirecting to home

        else:
            return json.dumps({'html':'<span>Enter the required fields</span>'})


    except Exception as e:
        return json.dumps({'error':str(e)})
    finally:
        cur.close() 
        conn.close()


@app.route("/")
def main():
     return(render_template('Senty.html'))
```

I'll also post terminal results just in case

```
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Apr/2018 21:45:06] "GET /showSignUp HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Registered
here
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Apr/2018 21:45:14] "POST /signUp HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: what happens then? Does it return any errors? Blank page?

Comment: @Daniel It just stays on the page, no errors. In the post below I was told to get rid of the except which helps. I now get the error "BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint '/'." But '/' is in my file and builds successfully other times. I've tried for_url(main) or for_url('/') as well.

Answer (score 1):

`return redirect(url_for('signUp'))` I believe it should be the name of the function.

Comment: That did not work either. I did get a GET /signUp HTTP/1.1 400 but not returning to home.

Comment: err ... I actually meant `return redirect(url_for('main'))`

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to use:

```
return redirect(url_for('/'))
```

Comment: I tried that as well. Still didn't register. I posted terminal results as well.

Comment: Ok. First, try to comment out your try-except block, because your `except` block will catch all exceptions - it is bad, you can't really understand what is the problem. Then check again, I think you can see the error here.

Comment: I now get the error "BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint '/'." But '/' is in my file and builds successfully other times. I'll add '/' to my code here

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your "/" route

```
@app.route("/")
def main():
     return(render_template('Senty.html'))
```

The correct code is:

```
return render_template('Senty.html')
```

Comment: While the line looks like `return` is used as a function, it is still a valid syntax and interpreted as `return (render_template('Senty.html'))`, with the value in parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

You could directly use `return(render_template('Senty.html'))` in your code like so:

```
@app.route('/signUp',methods=['POST','GET'])
def signUp():

    conn = mysql.connect()
    cur = conn.cursor()

    try:
        ...
        ...

        return(render_template('Senty.html'))


        else:
            ...

    except Exception as e:
        ...
    finally:
        ...
```

**Solution 2:**

Or you could use `return redirect(url_for('main'))` in the code above instead.

This is basically a summary of the correct answers before mine.